# Declaring a vector throws a runtime error in NetBeans

Tags: c++, vector, netbeans, runtime-error

I'm trying to learn about vectors in C++, but just trying to declare one throws a runtime error in NetBeans.

Error: Run failed (exit value -1, 073, 741, 511, total time 51 ms)

PS: The code works perfectly in Eclipse.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
// create a vector to store int
vector<int> vec;
int i;

// display the original size of vec
cout << "vector size = " << vec.size() << endl;

// push 5 values into the vector
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vec.push_back(i);
}

// display extended size of vec
cout << "extended vector size = " << vec.size() << endl;

// access 5 values from the vector
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << "value of vec [" << i << "] = " << vec[i] << endl;
}

// use iterator to access the values
vector<int>::iterator v = vec.begin();
while (v != vec.end()) {
    cout << "value of v = " << *v << endl;
    v++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Status: no repro](https://ideone.com/Yccfz2). If it works perfectly in eclipse, then what is the question?

Comment: The code seems ok, so it has to be your IDE settings or compiler, but we can't help you without more info.

Comment: Incomputable, the problem is that in my college the main IDE to use is NetBeans for some reason.

xander, there is really nothing more to it. It's just that the code doesn't work in NetBeans, but works in Eclipse.
I'm using G++ compiler if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on my system (latest GCC and NB dev build) and it works without any problem. The desired output is shown. It also runs fine from command line.

Therefore I assume it's more a configuration or system related problem. But without any further informations it's impossible to find the root cause.

---

#### More *information* please:

1. What ***OS / Environment*** are you using?
2. What ***Compiler*** (and versions) do you have?
3. What ***version*** of ***Netbeans*** do you use?
4. Do other project's work?

---

#### Here's some *first aid* you can try:

1. Create a new C++ Project (C++ Application). It already includes a blank `main()` function. Run this and check if there's still an error
2. Create a simple .cpp file and build it from command line (don't involve any IDE). Does it work this way?
3. Build and your source file without IDE. From Commandline: `g++ <your filename>.cpp`
4. Review your compiler settings (**`Tools -> Options -> C/C++`** at **`Build Tools`**). Especially use the ***Version*** button and check if everything is right.
5. Windows only: Make sure you have the correct make executable selected in the compiler settings
6. Have a look at the IDE's log (**`View -> IDE Log`**). Are there any problems mentioned?
7. Run in Debug *without* any breakpoint. This is going to stop the execution on any runtime error.

Comment: OS: Windows 10
Compiler: GCC
NetBeans 8.2
Other projects do work completely fine.

Have tried making a hello world program before posting and it worked fine, other previously written programs work fine too.

I have tried everything you mentioned except debugging as I don't have the necessary debugging tools or something, I forgot the exact error, but I don't think it's the compiler's fault, because as I said it works on Eclipse using the exact same settings.

Comment: What happens if you copy & paste the code from above into the working hello world program? Just for clarity: The compilation works, but the run fails. What you can try next: Run the compiled application from terminal (open a terminal, `cd` to where your binary is and launch it). Maybe there's more error text. If you have some time, you can install `gdb` as debugger (if not yet included with the GCC Toolchain). It's helpful anyway…

Comment: Oh, one more potential troublemaker: Does your project or toolchain path contain any blanks (` `)? This can be problematic on windows.